# Modelling Interfaces provided by different IPC frameworks

Tags: architecture, middleware

I'm stuck with a problem, where I don't know how to model interfaces that are provided by different IPC frameworks.

Let's say, there is a camera component and two arbitrary components C1 and C2. The camera has an interface for retrieving health data like temperature, errors and so on and an interface for retrieving the actual images.

Both interfaces are provided, using different kinds of IPC frameworks. The "HealthData" interface is provided via a framework that implements a pub/sub pattern. The camera publishes the data to a specific topic and C2 subscribes to this topic.
In contrast, the "Image" interface is provided via a different framework, that provides the image via a memory address and C3 is using that interface to retrieve the image.

My goal is to create a brief overview, how the different components are connected, which interfaces they provide / request and by which framework the interfaces are provided.

My first approach was to use ports to describe the IPC frameworks and to use exposed interfaces to specify which interface is provided or requested. Below is a picture of my approach.
[image]

My question is: How would you model this? I'm fairly new to UML and I'm not quiet sure, if this is the right way.

Comment: Look fine to me.

Comment: Look fine to me too. I would add a reference (label) to each Interface with the name of the IPC. Or the protocol underneath.